# Structure in two header files but with same name

Tags: visual-c++, header

I have these two header files in the following path:

```
...\xfs\XFS_WINCOR_03\INCLUDE_03_00\xfsbcr.hpp
...\xfs\XFS_WINCOR_03\INCLUDE_03_10\xfsbcr.hpp
```

Both of them have structures called `wfs_bcr_status`.

This structure is different in each header file but have the same name.

```
INCLUDE_03_00\xfsbcr.hpp

typedef struct wfs_bcr_status
{
    WORD            fwDevice;
    WORD            fwBCRScanner;
    DWORD           dwGuidLights[WFS_BCR_GUIDLIGHTS_SIZE];
    LPSTR           lpszExtra;
} WFSBCRSTATUS, * LPWFSBCRSTATUS;

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

INCLUDE_03_10\xfsbcr.hpp

typedef struct wfs_bcr_status
{
    WORD            fwDevice;
    WORD            fwBCRScanner;
    DWORD           dwGuidLights[WFS_BCR_GUIDLIGHTS_SIZE];
    LPSTR           lpszExtra;
    WORD            wDevicePosition;
    USHORT          usPowerSaveRecoveryTime;
} WFSBCRSTATUS, * LPWFSBCRSTATUS;
```

In my code I have a `cdm_device` class that is derived from the `device` class.

In `device` I include the first header and I use the structure in my methods.

```
#include "INCLUDE_03_00/xfsbcr.h"
```

In `cdm_device` i include the second header.

```
#include "INCLUDE_03_00/xfsbcr.h"
```

In my methods, when I want to get `wDevicePosition` and `usPowerSaveRecoveryTime`, I get an error because it's not recognizing the second header file (03_10) and look into the first header file (03_00) and they are not define there.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Aren't you supposed to do `#include "INCLUDE_03_10/xfsbcr.h` as the second header ? Notice that it should be **03_10** in the second case. You are including the same header in either cases.

Comment: Let's not discuss about all the points why it is a really bad idea to have two different structures with the same name. Maybe you have your reasons. I assume you are stumbling across similar include guards in both files. So the compiler just includes the "first" one.

Comment: @Mahesh: I did include that.

Comment: @pag3faul7: I know its bad idea and since i couldn't find a decent way for that im gonna use 1 header file and changing the name of structures, Thx for all reply s